# Alfresco: How do I view which associations a item has been made a part of?

Tags: alfresco

I have two custom types: `sc:foo` and `sc:bar`.

`sc:foo` has an association with `sc:bar`:

```xml
<type name="sc:bar">
    <title>Bar</title>
    <parent>cm:content</parent>
</type>
<type name="sc:foo">
    <title>Foo</title>
    <parent>cm:content</parent>
    <associations>
        <association name="sc:someAssociation">
            <title>Some Association</title>
            <source>
                <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                <many>false</many>
            </source>
            <target>
                <class>sc:bar</class>
                <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                <many>true</many>
            </target>
        </association>
    </associations>
</type>
```

In **web-client-config-custom.xml** I have the following so that when looking at an `sc:foo`, I can see which `sc:bar`'s it is assocated with.

```xml
<config evaluator="node-type" condition="sc:foo">
    <property-sheet>
        <show-association name="sc:someAssociation" />
    </property-sheet>
</config>
```

**Is there a way for me to look at a `sc:bar` and see which associations it has been made a  part of?**

I am using Alfresco Explorer 3.3 Enterprise.

Answer (score 2):

Although NodeService API allows yout to get source nodes from any assoc, the JSF client of Alfresco is not capable of showing them, and since the JSF client is no longer being enhanced this feature will not be added [ALFCOM-588](https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/ALFCOM-588).

So, either you implement yourself this feature or also you can follow @vegemite4me advice and keep two associations, in which case you should also implement onDeleteAssociation and onCreateAssociation policies to keep them in sync.

Answer (score 1):

Would two way binding fix your problem ? Not saying that is a nice way.

```xml
<type name="sc:bar">
    <title>Bar</title>
    <parent>cm:content</parent>
      <associations>
        <association name="sc:someAssociation">
            <title>Some Association</title>
            <source>
                <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                <many>false</many>
            </source>
            <target>
                <class>sc:foo</class>
                <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                <many>true</many>
            </target>
        </association>
    </associations>
</type>
```

Or you can create new custom panel in document details and show all bars that are associated to foo file, so this information would not be a part of standard form that you are working with.